# Testing Foreign Android Apps

Tags: android, ios, google-play

I've developed an android application that has been distributed in a foreign country. When I uploaded it to the play store, I didn't go through alpha & beta testing I just promoted it the play store directly. Now we've had a couple of issues with the application but as it was distributed in a foreign country, we couldn't download it.

I fixed the problems and re-uploaded the application to the play store with no issues. I then added a test project to google play store and put it through alpha testing again only distributing it to a foreign country. Even in alpha test, I cannot download the application as it says I am not allowed the app in this country (the UK).

I feel like this is very poor because it stops me knowing what the app looks like once it's been uploaded (Even going through the process of testing the application before it went live, there were still issues with the app). As the client we developed this app for is also based in a foreign country (The same as where the app was distributed), they found the issues before us.

**What I've Tried**

- On the phone FTPing into a server that is situated in the same country as where the application is distributed,
- Rooting the device (Using SRSRoot for Android One Click) Which didn't work even though it said it had worked!
- Downloading apps to allow me to access foreign Google Play Stores (Needed to root the device)

So I have three questions:

1. How can I download and test a foreign application through the Google Play Store?
2. Is it possible to do this without rooting a device?
3. Is there any Test software (E.g. TestFlight for Ios as apple bought it and it now cannot be used for android) I can use instead of going through Alpha/Beta testing on the Google Play Store?

Any information on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.